# Query RavenDB index inside session - session is not a unit of work?

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb, unit-of-work

I'm working on a proof-of-concept of a CQRS/ES architecture and we're evaluating RavenDB as a potential document store for some of the read models.

I am using the asynchronous session `IAsyncDocumentSession` for two reasons:

- The read model projection pipeline is fully asynchronous and optimised for interleaved processing
- I expect that having a unit of work with in-memory caching should improve performance

However, when I run a query (with an index), I do not get the documents I had added to the current session, even when specifying `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite`. 
This means that I cannot update these documents and end up creating new documents instead.

I use a repository to access RavenDB:

```
public async Task<ItemDistribution> FindAsync(Guid warehouse, Guid location, Guid item)
{
    var list = await this.Session
        .Query<ItemDistribution, ItemDistribution_WarehouseLocationItem>()
        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
        .Where(x => x.Warehouse == warehouse && x.Location == location && x.Item == item)
        .ToListAsync();
    // split for debugging purposes
    return list.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Once I call `SaveChangesAsync()`, this causes the documents to be added to the store and the next query then finds the saved documents.

This, to me, would indicate that a RavenDB session does not act as a unit of work when querying?

I did not want to add the key (warehouse, location, item) to the document identifier because the documentation discourages that.

What other options do I have available to quickly create or update documents in my projections?

**Update**

It seems to work if I track the documents in my own unit of work (i.e. a dictionary) and only hit the session/DB when I did not find it. I'm not sure if that is a good solution - the performance did however increase to handling several thousand (or tens of thousand) events per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Queries are not part of the session's unit of work.**

The results might be added to the unit of work, but the actual query runs against the DB.
The solution to my issue here is to use a compound key for the document and use `Load` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The RavenDB session implements the unit of work pattern.
I wasn't able to follow the problem as stated in the post, but in general, any *document* in the session (through `Load` or `Query`) is tracked by the RavenDB session, and will be checked for changes when `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: Simply put my issue is that any documents that are not yet saved, but have been added to the unit of work, are not found when issuing a query. I.e. I have called `Store(document)`, but not `SaveChanges` - and I did not load the document previously because it is a new document.